# Sitecore forms datepicker

Tags: sitecore-forms

Are there any modules in sitecore marketplace that provide Datepicker Field (with jquery and input type text) because as you can see, sitecore 9.3 forms date has input type date so it won't work in IE 11 or mac safari. I wonder if there are any modules out there or another solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this issue is already registered as a bug, did you try to reach to sitecore support to see if there is any fix released?

Otherwise in order to implement a workaround you would need to modify the `/Views/FormBuilder/FieldTemplates/Date.cshtml` and add additional script logic there. You can take a look at some solutions posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534118/datepicker-support-in-ie11-and-firefox

Comment: Hi thanks, i have also seen the article. But i hope there is a module out there so i could just install it haha